# If AL contains I or 3, display "o"; if AL contains 2 or 4, dlisplay "e" in assembly code

Tags: assembly, emu8086, microprocessors

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 100H 
.DATA 

A DB 10,13,'ENTER THE NUMBER: $' 
C DB 10,13,'RESULT $' 
.CODE 
MAIN PROC 

    MOV AX,@DATA 
    MOV DS,AX 

    MOV AH,9 
    LEA DX,A 
    INT 21H 
    
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H 
    
    
    MOV AH,9 
    LEA DX,C 
    INT 21H  
    
    CMP AL,1 
    JE ODD
    CMP AL,3
    JE ODD
    CMP AL,2
    JE EVEN
    CMP AL,4
    JE EVEN 
     
    ODD:
        MOV DL,'o'
        JMP DISPLAY  
     
    EVEN:
        MOV DL,'e'
        JMP DISPLAY
    
    DISPLAY:
    MOV AH,2
    INT 21h  
      
    EXIT: 
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I don't seem to understand what's wrong with the code. It was supposed to give the output 'o' if there was an input of 1 or 3 & an output of 'e' if there was an input of 2 or 4. it doesn't matter what I input 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, the output shows 'o' all the time. The Even level doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Printing the `C` message destroys `AL`.

Comment: (after fixing the bug Jester spotted), you can simplify to `test al, 1` / `jz even` to just check the low bit.  That will work for ASCII codes like `'1'` (0x31) as well as small numbers like 1.  **Single-step your code with a debugger and look at register values.** EMU8086 has a debugger built-in, that's why you're using it.

Comment: Should I just delete the portion where it deletes the output message of C? I'm new to assembly, so having a hard time learning it :(

Comment: You can just save the AX register (AX is (AL,AH)) by surrounding the output of the C message by `PUSH AX` ... print C message ... `POP AX`.  This will save the `AL` value for further processing.

Comment: Or just `mov cl, al` to save it for later in a different register.